# Linear Algebra, Quadric form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Question from an exercise

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$
  with $charF\neq2$. If $\varphi,\psi\in V^{\vee}$
 are linear functionals, we will define $\varphi\cdot\psi \colon V \rightarrow F$
  by $(\varphi\cdot \psi)(v) := \varphi(v)\cdot\psi(v)$
 .

1) Prove that $\varphi\cdot\psi$ is a quadric form;

2)Show that every quadric form $g:V\rightarrow F$ can be written as sum of quadric forms in the form $\varphi \cdot\psi$ for some linear functionals $\varphi$ and $\psi$ in $V^{\vee}$.

I proved the first one, which was pretty easy. But I have problem proving the second one.

My idea was basically showing that there is ismorphism between the vector space $Q=\{g:V\rightarrow F|
  g  \text{ is a quadric form} \}$ 
and the vector space $Z=\{\varphi \cdot \psi|\varphi,\psi\in V^{\vee}\}$

In other words I created a linear mapping $\sigma:Q\rightarrow Z$
and tried to show that it is linear and bijective. I succeeded showin that it is linear and injective but I couldn't show that it  is surjective. I could show that $\operatorname{Im}\sigma = Z$ , however I would have to show that $\dim Q=\dim Z$.  And I couldn't do it. Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: A pedant's remark: The set $Z$ that you wrote down is not a vector space. You usually cannot write $\phi_1\cdot\psi_1+\phi_2\cdot\psi_2$ in the form $\phi\cdot\psi$. This is why question 2 specifically talks about **sums** of quadratic forms of the type $\phi\cdot\psi$. This may or may not be related to your difficulties. BTW, what's the definition of a quadratic form you are using?

Comment: Definition : V is a vector space over the field F ($charF \neq 2) $ with symmetric bilinear form $B:V \times V \rightarrow F$, then quadric form is the transformation $g:V \rightarrow F$ such that $g(v)=B(v,v)$ 

You are right... I thought it would be a vector space since it has elements from Q, Then what I am trying to do will definitely now work. Thanks for the warning!

I will try another way then. Thanks for the feedback!